# How to pass an object name to a JavaScript promise that waits until the object has been initiated?

Tags: javascript

I need a function that resolves a JavaScript promise as soon as an object is defined.

I'm a WordPress plugin developer and I face the problem that I have no control over where my code is placed in the website (some third party JavaScript "optimization" plugins even can jumble the code around). And I don't have control over the objects I am trying to check. In the example of `jQuery`, my code could be placed above or below jQuery, and my code depends on `jQuery`.

I imagine the following:

```
function objectExists(object) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        (function waitForObject() {
            if (object) return resolve();
            setTimeout(waitForObject, 30);
        })();
    });
}


objectExists(jQuery).then(function () {
  // run my code
}
```

The problem is that the browser will error out at the line `objectExists(jQuery).then(function () {`, telling that `jQuery` is not defined.

When I write the promise to **only** check for `jQuery` it works.

```
function jQueryExists() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        (function waitForJQuery() {
            if (jQuery) return resolve();
            setTimeout(waitForJQuery, 30);
        })();
    });
}
```

But, I want to be able to pass any object name to the function, before that object hast been defined. How do I do that?

Comment: It's really unlikely that this is the best solution to your problem. It's almost never advisable to "poll" for some side-effect in your code when you can just use event handlers to listen for the actual condition to occur.

Comment: "*I need a function that resolves a JavaScript promise as soon as an object is defined.*" - then construct the promise and **resolve it from the code that defines the object**. Don't repeatedly test whether it is defined or not.

Comment: @meagar I'm a WordPress plugin developer and I face the problem that I have no control over where my code is placed in the website. In the example of jQuery, my code could be placed above or below jQuery, and my code depends on jQuery. I also don't like to poll. But I'm not familiar with the concept that you are referring to. Could you please point me to a possible solution with event handlers?

Comment: @Bergi: But I don't have control over that third party code, like `jQuery`. So I can't  "resolve it from the code that defines the object". Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: @alev Surely in wordpress, [a script can declare jQuery as its dependency](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) - at least that's what I found from 1min of googling

Comment: "*some third party plugins even can jumble the code around*" - I would think that's their problem if they break the scripts, not yours.

Comment: @Bergi: _"a script can declare jQuery as its dependency"_ -  True, which I did. But, I face the problem that third party JavaScript "optimization" plugins sometimes jumble the code around (minification, combination, deferring, etc.) and some of those don't care about that I declared my script as a dependency.

Comment: @Bergi: _"I would think that's their problem if they break the scripts, not yours"_ - True, in a way. But the website owners who are using my plugin and the JavaScript optimizers, don't care which plugin is causing the issue. I still get the support requests and unhappy users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the object will be global, pass a string and use `typeof` instead, which will work for variables that haven't been defined yet:

```
function objectExists(varName) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        (function waitForObject() {
            if (typeof window[varName] !== 'undefined') return resolve();
            setTimeout(waitForObject, 30);
        })();
    });
}


objectExists('jQuery').then(function () {
  // run my code
});
```

(or you could use your existing code with `window.jQuery` instead - referencing a non-existent property of an object won't throw an error)

But this is a really weird thing to want to do. Better to attach a `load` listener to the jQuery `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thanks. But I can't "attach a load listener to the jQuery <script> tag" because I don't have control over those objects and scripts I was referring to. I should have better specified this in my question. I added more context now.

Comment: Wonderful. The proposed solution works! Trying `window.jQuery` doesn't throw the error (as you suggested), but for some reason never resolves the promise.