# How do I check if my function is loaded with a promise which is out of order?

Tags: javascript

I want to load two functions which are in two different files. Function B depends upon function A to be available.

Usually I would simply order the files in a way that they get loaded sequentially. But, I am a WordPress developer and there are third party JavaScript "optimization" plugins around that sometimes jumble the the ordering around and let my scripts fail.

A Stackoverflow expert wrote me to "[resolve it from the code that defines the object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67454028/4688612)", but it seems promises are to me like the movie Tenet. All looks logical in a way, but as soon as I want to think it through, I can't come up with a logical solution.

The following solution works only if the two get loaded in the right order,
but it will not work the other way around.

```
// a.js
// this is in one file with function A

let isMyFunctionReady = Promise.resolve(true);

// b.js
// this is in another file with function B
isMyFunctionReady.then(function(){
    console.log('Yes, my function is ready, I can now use it.');
}).catch(function () {
    console.log('Couldnt load my function');
})
```

But, the following won't work:

```
// b.js
// this is in another file with function B
isMyFunctionReady.then(function(){
    console.log('Yes, my function is ready, I can now use it.');
}).catch(function () {
    console.log('Couldnt load my function');
})

// a.js
// this is in one file with function A
let isMyFunctionReady = Promise.resolve(true);
```

I know I can do this with a timeout and poll every 50ms or so to see if function A exists. But that is not what I want.

I have the feeling that maybe jQuery Deferred could be used. But again, it's as clear as Tenet to me.

How do I approach this?

Comment: Hi, **Async** and **await**  dosent work??

Comment: Maybe. I'm not familiar enough with **async** and **await** to know. I'll look into it.

Comment: if you want show me all of your code and i help you as i can

Comment: How are these scripts loaded?

Comment: `async`/`await` is really just syntax sugar over promises, so i it doesn't work with promises, I doubt it will with `async`/`await`...

Comment: @FZs: Using `wp_enqueue_script`. But some JavaScript "optimization" plugins don't care about the order and dependencies that I've set up, and therefore in certain cases break my code.

Comment: Did you set the `$deps` argument correctly? Can you show that part of your code too?

Comment: @FZs: `['jquery', 'handler-a']`

Comment: That should work. Without more context, this can't be reproduced. What's your optimization plugin? Where (and how) do you enqueue the other scripts? Any other thing that may be related but you didn't tell yet? Please edit these things into the question, so that the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: @FZs: The question is very clear I think. How do I resolve a promise if can't follow the proper order of setting up a promise.

Comment: I understand your question, just that if you don't know which script will be loaded first, you don't have any way to connect them (not even with promises) without making either polling for the other. So, your actual question is, that "How can I tell WP to load the script my script depends on first?", for which more details are required.

Comment: Ok. You're saying without polling that can't be done. That's an answer. I know how to tell WP to load the scripts in order. But there are various JavaScript "optimization" plugins out there that don't respect the instructions and sometimes change the order in which I have set up the scripts, breaking my script flow as a consequence. The only way to work around this in general is to have a way to re-sequence the order somehow. If possible I want to avoid polling.

Comment: a) Is there some kind of module loader (like *require.js*) in wordpress or are all scripts loaded in the global scope? b) Do you control the source of both files (or is the dependency an external lib - like *jQuery* - that you cannot modify)?

Comment: Can you share more details about these broken "optimisation" plugins? Can you file bugs against them? In general, if they mess with your code in arbitrary ways, you can never write code that works with all plugins.

Comment: @Bergi: a) Only `wp_enqueue_script` that includes a dependency setting, which gets ignored by some JavaScript optimization plugins (thus my headache). b) Yes.

Comment: @Bergi: _"Can you share more details about these broken "optimisation" plugins?"_  -There are maybe 20 of which I know of. For most of them I already have some sort of workarounds. But I get support requests almost daily still, because some of those optimization plugins have added some "feature" and break my code over again. It's a pain. _"you can never write code that works with all plugins."_ - Well, my hope is that I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single promise indeed won't help you here if you cannot control the order of execution. Instead, each script will need to look whether it is executed first, and then set up your custom order-independent module dependency system. Have a look at the [asynchronous module definition API](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md) for inspiration. You can use one of the libraries that implement it (like *require.js*) or create your own.

For simplicity, I'll show the usage of jQuery deferreds<sup>1</sup> here:

```
// file a.js
/* the shared part: */
if (!window.isMyFunctionReady) window.isMyFunctionReady = $.Deferred();

/* the definition part: */
window.isMyFunctionReady.resolve(true);
```

```
// file b.js
/* the shared part: */
if (!window.isMyFunctionReady) window.isMyFunctionReady = $.Deferred();

/* the usage part: */
window.isMyFunctionReady.promise().then(value => {
    console.log(`Yes, my function ${value} is ready, I can now use it`);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
});
// optional:
setTimeout(() => {
    window.isMyFunctionReady.reject(new Error("Didn't load in time"));
}, 1000);
```

<sub>1: Of course this assumes that jQuery is always already available. If not, you'll have to put the code for the deferred objects in the "shared parts" as well.</sub>

Comment: Thanks you very much!